# What is the Python3 equivalent to Excel's =NORMDIST(100,200,25,0)

Tags: python, excel, scipy

In Excel =NORMDIST(100,200,25,0) puts out 0.000535321%. How do I get that same value in Python?

I have tried using scipy.stats.norm but it gives different results.

Comment: What did you try? `scipy.stats.norm.pdf(100,200,25)` seems to be correct.

Comment: @GeneralGrievance Thank you, it was my mistake I was using norm.cdf

Comment: Ah, that would be equivalent if the last argument was 1.